# import function from standard library after importing similarly named function from other library

Tags: python, numpy, standard-library

This is a curiosity. Say I am using **IPython** interactively, which by default imports

```
from numpy import sum
```

and after that I decide to use `sum` from the standard library. Say, to do something like

```
texts = [['a','good','day'],['a','lovely','day']]
sum(texts, [])
```

Can I do that? How?

- *Notice that I don't need a solution for flattening a list. I want a general solution for importing the standard library as if I were importing any other library, or a way to circumvent the shadowing of a function.*

Answer (score 2):

You can access it under `__builtin__` (Python 2) or `builtins` (Python 3):

```
>>> from numpy import sum
>>> texts = [['a','good','day'],['a','lovely','day']]
>>> sum(texts, [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
>>> __builtin__.sum(texts, [])
['a', 'good', 'day', 'a', 'lovely', 'day']
>>> from __builtin__ import sum
>>> sum(texts, [])
['a', 'good', 'day', 'a', 'lovely', 'day']
```

But two points:

(1) IPython does *not* import numpy's sum by default-- unless you're working in a legacy `pylab` mode, in which case you shouldn't. :-)

(2) `sum` isn't a great example because using `sum(something, [])` to concatenate lists will show quadratic behaviour and so should generally be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! Example taken from [gensim tutorial](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html).